# Powershell: conditional join delimiter for empty array (ignore delimiter if empty)?

Tags: arrays, powershell, join, delimiter, csv

I'm new to PowerShell and could not find a proper answer to this one:

I'm building a script that may require some manual modification at times. There is an array that is giving me grief when it is empty due to a join.  I am not sure how to evaluate the array for when it is empty while preserving my lazy delimiter.

```
$array = @() -join '|'
```

In this case: '$array.count' returns 1, whereas I'd prefer to skip the -join if empty and return '0'.
Is there a way to make the join conditional based on a populated array?

Comment: You actually just get an empty string when you do `@() -join '|'`.  `-join` will always return a single string.  It's job is to combine all the elements in the array (their tostring() values) with your given delimiter into a single string

Comment: Did I mention that -join will always give you a single string?  :)  $array.count will always be 1 whether the array you are joining has 0 items or 1000 items

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a conditional somewhere in your code to make it work. If the array count is equals to one, in your case, it means it is empty. For example:

```
if($array.count -le 1) { ... }
```